# Several buttons + one text field in a form

Tags: php, html, jquery

I have a loop that displays in a form buttons whose name comes from a MYSQL database + variables passed by the url of the previous page ($postvalue).
Each button send to the result.php file.

If a text is entered in the common text entry field, I have to retrieve in the result.php page the value of $postvalue + the value of the text field.

I can't get the text field in result.php.

-- example My form --

[image]

-- buttons.php --

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<textarea id="info" name="info" placeholder="Info..." style="height:50px" rows="5" cols="33"></textarea>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#info").change(function() {
var info = document.getElementById('info').value;
});
});
</script>


<?php  foreach( $datas as $data ) { 
$postvalue = array('string01' => $_GET['value01'],'string02' => $_GET['value02'],'string03' => $_GET['value03']);
$postvalue = base64_encode(serialize($postvalue));
?>
<form action='result.php' method='post'>
<button id="button" class="button" name='submit' value='0'><?php echo $data->button;?></button>
<input type="hidden" name="result" value="<?php echo $postvalue; ?>">
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

-- result.php --

```
<?php // result.php
if ($_POST['result']) {
    $postvalue = unserialize(base64_decode($_POST['result']));
    print_r($postvalue);
}
?>
```

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: I can't get the text field in result.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `textarea` is outside any of the `forms` you create, so its value is not passed to result.php.

I would suggest to change your logic, create only one form, containing the textarea and the buttons. Instead of passing the `$postvalue` as a hidden field for each form, simply pass it as value of the `submit` buttom.

So in code

--- buttons.php

```
<form action='result.php' method='post'>
    <textarea id="info" name="info" placeholder="Info..." style="height:50px" rows="5" cols="33"></textarea>
    <?php
    foreach ($datas as $data) {
        $postvalue = array('string01' => $_GET['value01'],'string02' => $_GET['value02'],'string03' => $_GET['value03']);
        $postvalue = base64_encode(serialize($postvalue));
        ?>
        <button id="button" class="button" name='result' type="submit" value='<?php echo $postvalue; ?>'><?php echo $data->button;?></button>
        <?php
    }
    ?> 
</form>
```

---result.php

```
<?php

if ($_POST['result']) {
    $postvalue = unserialize(base64_decode($_POST['result']));
    print_r($postvalue);
    echo $_POST['info']; // This is the textarea text
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, finally it was so simple.
I had wanted to complicated it by using the Jquery. ERROR